# Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion missing variables

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

A survey of 100 students taken over the last year revealed that

1. 30 of them smoke
2. 50 of them drink
3. 20 of them smoke and drink
4. 25 go to the gym regularly, and of these, none smokes nor drinks.

Calculate how many of the 100 students neither smoke, nor drink, nor go to the gym.

---

So by the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion, we should u

$$A^{c}B^{c}C^{c} = |U|-(|A|+|B|+|C|)+(|AB|+|AC|+|BC|)-|ABC|$$
$$= 100 - (30+50+25)+(20+X+Y)-Z$$

This is where I get stuck...

Comment: A Venn diagram is often way easier.

Comment: I still wouldn't be able to fill it out.

Comment: You sure?  The 3-way intersection is empty, and that lets you fill in $S \cap D$.  The rest works out.  The answer is 15.

Comment: But isn't that exactly what I am trying to figure out.. So essentially you are saying I need to find $S \cap D \cap G$?

Comment: The regions $S \cap D \cap G$, $S \cap G$, and $D \cap G$ must ALL be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ought to be 15. I worked this out using a Venn diagram, as follows:

1. Draw a rectangle and write 100 in one of its corners. That's the whole student body.
2. Draw two intersecting circles, one for smokers and one for drinkers. Write 20 in the overlap, for those who drink and smoke. Now, the remainder of the smoking circle is 10 people, so write that in; the remainder of the drinking circle is 30 people, so write that in.
3. Write 25 outside both circles for the people who go to the gym.

Now you can see that the total number of people contained in the circles is $10 + 20 + 30 = 60$. Then you have the 25 people at the gym. The total is 85, so 15 people do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to what you asked. Your formula for using the PIE is correct.

You just need to figure out what the values are for $X, Y$, and $Z$. For $X(=AC)$, it means the number of people who smoke and they don’t smoke which of course is $0$. Similarly for $Y(=BC)=0$.

Now, $Z=ABC=A(BC)=A0=0$. In summary, $X$ and $Y$ and $Z$ are all $0$. Plugging them into your formula, you get $15$.